# How to integrate Prettier into a shareable ESLint configuration?

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

One can create [shareable ESLint configs](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/shareable-configs) to use in multiple projects. It is also possible to integrate Prettier settings into an ESLint config like so:

```
[...]

rules: {
'prettier/prettier': [
  'error',
  {
    printWidth: 120,
    tabWidth: 2,
    useTabs: false,
    semi: false,
    singleQuote: true,
  },
],

[...]
```

However, when I do this with my shared config I can't get it to work. When I run `eslint --fix` it just does nothing at all. How can I integrate ESLint and Prettier somewhere and then just extend my local ESLint with that configuration so I don't have to configure the exact same thing in 20 different repositories?